# Google Sheets: Use Custom Headers For Grouped QUERY()

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I've added a grouped QUERY() which groups the Stocks in an ETF by Sector, for use in a Chart, which works fine. However I'd like the resultant range to use custom headers, and use a descending order.

The data:

[image]

The query result:

[image]

First I tried to add custom headers using "AS" but this failed:

`=QUERY(F9:I114,"select F as 'Sector', sum(I) as 'Weight', count(I) as 'Stocks' group by F")`

Then I tried to ORDER the result, no luck either:

`=QUERY(F9:I114,"select F, sum(I), count(I) group by F order F desc")`

[edit] Correction, I found that "ORDER" should be "ORDER BY" which works with col F, but I actually want to order by the SUM(I), so successfully used:

`=QUERY(F9:I114,"select F, sum(I), count(I) group by F order by sum(I) desc")`

My SQL is quite rusty, and I haven't found any relevant examples, so any suggestions would be appreciated.  MTIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good job, you are pretty close. QUERY() is based on SQL but like all implementations have its own nuances and QUERY() is not a full implementation. You can change the headers using the LABEL clause. You are correct regarding the ORDER BY.

Change this:

```
=QUERY(F9:I114,"select F as 'Sector', sum(I) as 'Weight', count(I) as 'Stocks' group by F")
```

to this:

```
=QUERY(F9:I114,"select F , sum(I), count(I) group by F LABEL F 'Sector', SUM(I) 'Weight', COUNT(I) 'Stocks' ORDER BY SUM(I) DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks John, the LABEL was what I was missing.  Note however that it initially failed, and after trying a few combinations, I found from the error msg that the LABEL section had be be placed after the  ORDER BY.  Cheers, Max